# device is already associated with other accounts the Apple Developer Program or the Apple Developer Enterprise Program

Tags: xcode, apple-id

how can I remove my others account. It's also important for me. how can I fix it. I have seen many solution like make new admin. why I need to make new admin in my device if I already have my own apple id everything is connected with it. without adding Apple ID how will I upload build.

I am unable to add new Apple ID in my device.

Comment: How you have fixed that?